# Is there a simple way to edit an answer to make scriptural references hyper links?

Tags: support, hyperlinks

I answered a question and included lots of scripture citations but it is not easy to read like others who make hyper links to, for example, bible gateway.  How can I edit to make this happen?

Comment: Even though you can use hyper links it is much easier for the reader to follow if you quote the referenced Scripture. Many of the site visitors are not familiar with the Bible and do not wish to spend a lot time searching references on the internet. If you are referencing a Web site using the hyper link is great since they can usually just click on the link to go there. Not scolding just giving you something to think about.

Answer (score 5):

It's not extremely simple, but it's easy once you get the hang of it.  There are basically two ways, as described in the [help center](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

The first method, the one I typically use, involves combining the reference and the URL in one line with a bit of formatting, like this:

> `[John 1:1](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John+1%3A1&version=ESV)`

Others prefer separating the link text from the URL, like this:

> `[John 1:1][1] Other text here, perhaps paragraphs and paragraphs.`
>
> `[1]: https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John+1%3A1&version=ESV`

Either way, you get a link like this:

> [John 1:1](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John+1%3A1&version=ESV)

Answer (score 4):

Use the built in link function:

[image]

Enter your link in the popup window:

[image]

Here's what you get in the markup:

```
 [enter link description here][1]

 [1]: http://website.tld
```

Change the text "enter your description here" to what every you want the text to be. The final product will look like this:

[enter link description here](http://website.tld)

This is the fastest and easiest way I have found and it organizes all your links at the bottom, like this:

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uW52.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctlPd.jpg
  [3]: http://website.tld
```

Comment: Are those tools available to an iPhone 6 without the app installed?

Comment: @Kris I don't know. Try requesting the desktop site from safari if you don't see it on mobile.